# How to change numeration style in the outline Boadilla style

Tags: beamer

I would like the numeration style of the outline and of all other lists. I want go from the first to the second picture:

[image]

[image]

I am trying with different combination of this code but it does not work:

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate}[plain]
```

Comment: Please always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions. Also please tag your beamer questions with `beamer` and not with `overleaf` - your questions are not overleaf specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]` to switch back all items to the default template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                    
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item test
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To set only the enumerate items:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                    
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item test
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the toc style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                    
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the outline still keeps having the old style